# Eclipse working set is missing

Tags: eclipse

My Eclipse crashed, and a working set which I'd just spent an hour setting up is now missing.

But when I try and create a new working set with the same name, it says "A working set with that name already exists."

So if it exists, where is it?  I can't find it in my workspace...
If it doesn't exist, why can't I create a new one of the same name?

I've tried refreshing my workspace (F5), and running ./eclipse -clean - no joy.

Comment: Which option is selected when you select **Top level elements** in your view (by click on the triangular icon) ? *Projects* or *Working Sets*?

Comment: I view stuff by working sets.  I have other ones, which are still there.  But searching in my workspace (`find . -exec grep 'name of a visible working set' {} \; -print`) doesn't give any results...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A little hack solved it :)
(Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Indigo Service Release 1)

1. Choose a project, right click on it.
2. Assign Working Sets...
3. In Working Set Assignments window: uncheck the checkbox called "Show only Package Explorer working sets" ... and voila: there is the disappeared working set.
4. Check that working set and Click "OK" -> Working set will appear in Package Explorer.

Comment: in Eclipse Photon (4.8) I had also to select all working sets that I want to see: click the "Configure Package Explorer working sets..." link under the checkbox "Show only Package Explorer working sets", select the checkbox of the  Working Sets you like to see, click "OK"

Comment: The hint from @AntoineWils also works on IBM Integration Toolkit 10.0.0.10 (Based in Eclipse Juno 4.2).

Comment: Didn't quite work for me, on the Package Explorer view (eclipse 2018-09), but helped to find what worked: same thing going to assign working sets but then choose 'Configure Package Explorer working sets' and check the missing working sets.

Answer (score 15):

Another possibility is to click the arrow pointing down (View Menu), select top level element and then choose Working sets.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of the above answers worked for me on STS 3.4.2. I kept getting the error "workspace of that name already exists" when I tried to create a specific name although I could not see it in the package viewer.

I found this file that contains references to the named workspaces:

```
<workspace dir>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workingsets.xml
```

I noticed that the missing workspace had a

```
 editPageId=org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui.springWorkingSetPage
```

whereas the ones I could see were:

```
editPageId=org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaWorkingSetPage
```

So, my 'missing' working set would only show up in the spring package viewer. User error - but eclipse did not help find it...

At this point one can either rename/delete the spring workspace, then add it to the package workspace.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to:

- Right click on a project > "Assign Working Sets..."
- "Configure Package Explorer working sets..."
- Select the missing working sets and click OK

Et voilà!

Comment: When  I do that, OK wont works , so I can save my changees ;(

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by closing then reopening Navigator view.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all for the hints. 
While they didn't exactly work as it did for some of you, here's what worked for me (using Eclipse Juno):

> File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace -> *Select the directory from where to import your project(s)* -> Finish.

Not sure what the specific cause was, though it happened when my machine crashed.