# Eclipse: Project Explorer: "Top level elements to working sets but no workings sets defined"

Tags: eclipse, project-explorer

Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Hi,

My Package Manager View is working file.
My Project Exlorer View shows nothing but this message:

"Top level elements to working sets but no workings sets defined"

A few weeks ago I made a working set.

I left my Eclipse on over the weekend.

When I came back my Eclipse was displaying only that working set.

Deselecting that working set did not restore the default display.

So, I deleted that working set and now the Project Explorer is empty save for that error message.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse working set is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099700/eclipse-working-set-is-missing)

Comment: It happened to me also when I imported a *2019-06* eclipse `PyDev` workspace in a fresh installed *2020-03* eclipse version. The solution of greg-449 worked for me **flawless**.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Click the small triangle at the top right of the Project Explorer view (the 'view menu').

Select 'Top Level Elements' and choose 'Projects'

Note that from Eclipse 2019-12 onwards the 'small triangle' is replaced by three vertical dots (the 'hamburger' menu).